# Change cell orientation from rows to columns

Tags: excel

Sorry for the bad title, I didn't know exactly how to phrase it. So.... I took a picture so that it may be more clear.

[image]

So as you can see, in the first pic, each customer starts in a new row. Customer A is in row 2, customer B is in row 3, Customer C is in row 4.

I want to change the orientation to what I show on the right. All the customers are on the same row, but on different columns. Is there a formula to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use a VBA macro, that'll be easier, at least if you have some basic programming skills.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really. I know the tiniest bit of Python. Maybe it's time I pick up some VBA

Answer (score 0):

If the data is exactly as in your picture, you can use the formula like this (enter it in `G2` and drag to the right):

```
=INDEX($A:$C,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,3),MOD((COLUMN()-7),3)+1)
```